# Configure User Secrets in .NET Core 2.1 Console Apps

Tags: c#, .net-core, console-application

I know that in `.NET Core MVC`, you can do it using the context menu, but this option is not available for `.NET Core Console` apps.

How can I add User Secrets to my .NET Core 2.1 Console Application?

Comment: That's described in the documenation: [Safe storage of app secrets in development](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=windows). It works exactly the same in console applications

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Add the `<UserSecretsId>` tag in the `.csproj file`.**

```
<PropertyGroup>  
   <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
   <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.x</TargetFramework>
   <UserSecretsId>4245b512-chsf-9f08-09ii-12an1901134c</UserSecretsId>
</PropertyGroup>
```

**Open a command prompt window in your solution folder (the one with the `.csproj` file in it) and type**

```
dotnet user-secrets set SecretName SecretKey
```

Replace `SecretName` and `SecretKey` accordingly.

**You can then access it in your application using**

```
class Program
{ 
    private static IConfigurationRoot Configuration;
    const string SecretName= "SecretName";

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BootstrapConfiguration();
        Console.WriteLine($"The Secret key is {Configuration[SecretName]}");
    }
}

private static void BootstrapConfiguration()
{
    string env = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(env))
    {
        env = "Development";
    }

    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();

    if (env == "Development")
    {
        builder.AddUserSecrets<Program>();
    }

    Configuration = builder.Build();
}
```

Comment: Only in 2.1. What is the purpose of this question and answer?

Comment: No, it won't work on 2.0. There were no global tools in 2.0. This is already explained in the documentation and I'll bet there are a lot of *correct* duplicates

Comment: In 2.0 we had to add a tool entry in the project file. That's why there was a need for `Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools`. No packages are needed any more [as explained in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=windows).

Comment: [This article](https://cmatskas.com/configure-and-use-user-secrets-in-net-core-2-0-console-apps-in-development/) explains how to configure user secrets for 2.0. The first *two* packages are added as packages. The third one is added as a `DotNetCliToolReference`

Comment: Gotcha, fixed my question and answer for 2.1 since thats the one I was using in the first place. Thanks for the heads up @PanagiotisKanavos